# How to create a list of values depending on whether the corresponding value in another list is zero or not

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list, for-loop

I am working on modelling a solar system and need to model the temperature power loss. This depends on the irradiance level for the given hour. I am trying to write a script that calculates the corresponding value for power loss given the module temperature.

My end goal is to make it so that when the script reads each individual value of `total_irr` it calculates a corresponding value for `temp_loss`, unless `total_irr` is zero then `temp_loss` is also zero, and appends it to a list so I can create a data frame from all my results.

Below is the code I'm currently working with, and I think it is running 8760 times for 8760 values when I only need it to run through the values of `total_irr` once.

```
total_irr = df['Direct Irradiance'] + df['Diffuse Irradiance']
module_temp = t_dry + (((noct-20)/800)*total_irr)

def calc_temp_loss(irr):
    if irr > 0:
        temp_loss = (module_temp - 25) * power_coeff
    else:
        temp_loss = 0
    return temp_loss

power_loss_list = []
            
for irr in total_irr:
    power_loss = calc_temp_loss(irr)
    power_loss_list.append(power_loss)
```

I've also included a screenshot of the print statement I receive when attempting to print `power_loss_list`.
[image: Snippet of the print statement I receive]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: is `df` a _pandas_ dataframe? If so, please add that tag to your question. What is `module_temp` and `power_coeff`? Is it another dataframe/series or just scalars? Please make sure your code is a [mre]

Comment: @pho I require that when the value of `total_irr` is zero, the value for `temp_loss` is also zero. If I just do the calculation, I have none zero values when `total_irr` is zero.

Comment: @pho That has worked perfectly, thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to help! I added an answer, since that comment does actually answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a vectorized calculation for `temp_loss` the same way you did for `module_temp`:

```
temp_loss = (module_temp - 25) * power_coeff
```

This subtracts 25 from the entire `module_temp` series, then multiplies it by `power_coeff`

Next, you can set the elements corresponding to zero `total_irr` to zero:

```
temp_loss[total_irr == 0] = 0
```

Finally, get the sum of `temp_loss` with `temp_loss.sum()`